# trigger change() even on selecting the same value for select field

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've options like this

```
<select name="hall" id="hall">
  <option>1</option>
  <option>2</option>
  <option>3</option>
  <option>4</option>
  <option>5</option>
</select>
```

I'm using jquery function to submit my form

```
 $('#hall').change(
```

But when the same value is selected again, I want it to to be triggered.
How can i do this?

Comment: Related: [Getting value of select (dropdown) before change](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4076770/getting-value-of-select-dropdown-before-change)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do it on click

```
$('#hall').on('click',function(){

   if(this.selectedIndex == -1) {
      alert('select one answer');
   }
   else{
      // do whatever you want!
   }        
});
```

Comment: Simple and violent solution!

Comment: so when you use click event it wont allow you to select. check this jsfiddelhttp://jsfiddle.net/58phdcj0/

Comment: @MazzCris he can put a condition to check weather the value is selected or not and submit on the fullfilling the desired condition. I don't think it'd be that difficult.

Comment: In Firefox this call the function immediately, before having selected an option

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
var prevVal;
$('#hall').on('focus', function (){
     prevVal=$( "#hall:selected" ).text();
});

$('#hall').on('change', function (){
     if(prevVal=$( "#hall:selected" ).text()){
          alert('same val selected');
     }
});
```

Comment: I don't see how this would work, unless the assignment on line #7 is meant to be a comparison.

Answer (score 2):

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/faLfduck/1/)**

You can do as below:

```
$("#hall option").on('click',function(){
    $("#hall").trigger('change');
});
$("#hall").on('change',function(){
   alert('changed'); 
});
```

**Note : As per comment [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5749653/2065039) this works well in FF but not in chrome. You can use it at your own risk**

Comment: Not working in Edge, Chrome 2023.

Answer (score 0):

@Vibhesh Kaul solution worked for me on windows, but not for my client who is on a mac.

This is my solution:

```
var previous_value = '';
$(document).on('click', 'select#hall', function () {
  // click on select
  if(previous_value == '') {
    previous_value = $(this).val();
  }
  // click on option, check if same value is chosen
  else if($(this).val() == previous_value) {
    // trigger a change
    $(this).trigger('change');
  }
});

$(document).on('blur', 'select#hall', function () {
  // reset the previous value of the select
  previous_value = '';
});

$(document).on('change', 'select#hall', function () {
  alert('test example');
});
```