# Which <option> field is selected? With jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm looking for a way to find out which  field is selected with jQuery. I build a function, but it doesn't work.

HTML example

```
<select id="bewerbungID">
<option value="1" name="selectName">test1</option>
<option value="2" name="selectName">test2</option>
<option value="3" name="selectName">test3</option>
</select>
```

JS function

```
$('#bewerbungID select').on('change', function() {
   alert($('option[name=selectName]:checked', '#bewerbsungID').val()); 
});
```

Tested in jsfiddle [open link](https://jsfiddle.net/cayqcchm/)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jquery select option click handler](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5749597/jquery-select-option-click-handler)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Treat select as an input field such as text. Then it has to have a value selected - show new value whenever it changes. You logic was right but jQuery selectors got a bit confusing.

Simplified your code a bit:

```js
$('#bewerbungID').on('change', function() {
   alert($('#bewerbungID').val()); 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="bewerbungID">
<option value="1" name="selectName">test1</option>
<option value="2" name="selectName">test2</option>
<option value="3" name="selectName">test3</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue you are having is that you are not using the selector properly.

**Basic Explanation:**

The selector is everything you find within the parenthesis here: `$('...')`. When you use `#` in front of the word, that means you are selecting an element that has an id of whatever is to the right of `#`. In your case, `...` is equal to `#bewerbungID` so the proper code should be as follows:

```
$('#bewerbungID').on('change', function() {
  alert($('#bewerbungID').val());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#bewerbungID').on('change', function() {
   alert($('#bewerbsungID option:selected').val()); 
});
```

It should do the trick