# how to pick different API calls depending on the drop down option

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, api

Hi I would like to add a feature to my login page where the user has an option of choosing from a list of drop down options, each option has its own api linked depending on each api determines whether the user can login, how would i be able to link an api call to each menu option.

```
<label for="Hierarchy">hierarchy</label>
<select name="hierarchy" id="hierarchy" value="">
  <option value=""></option>
  <option value="Staff">staff</option>
  <option value="Teacher"> teacher</option>
  <option value="Student">student</option>
</select>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5749597/jquery-select-option-click-handler

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use jQuery's `.change()` event, and then use `this.value` to check which option was selected and thus run the corresponding API call using an `if` statement.

See example below:

```js
$("#hierarchy").change(function() { // Run this function when option selected
  let position = this.value;
  if(position == "Staff") {
    api_login('usa'/*ADD OTHER ARUGMENTS HERE*/);
  } else if(position == "Teacher") {
    api_login('france'/*ADD OTHER ARUGMENTS HERE*/);
  } else if(position == "Student") {
    api_login('uk'/*ADD OTHER ARUGMENTS HERE*/);
  } else {
    console.log("Stop/Don't run any API's");
  }
});


function api_login(country, dealer_code, userid_code, actionID = '10', VRN = '', filename = '') { /* ADD country AS A FIRST ARGUMENT */
  if (dealer_code === undefined || userid_code === undefined) {
    return false;
  }
  if (actionID === undefined) {
    actionID = '10';
  }
  var string = 'dealerID=' + dealer_code + '&salesExecID=' + userid_code + '&actionID=' + actionID + '&VRM=' + VRN + '&filename=' + filename;
  var querystring = country +'.snstest.judgeservice.co.uk/api.php?' + (string); /* CHANGE THIS LINE TO USE country */
  var error = [];

  $.getJSON(querystring, function(json) {
    var response = String(json.code);
    var message = String(json.message);
    var ident = String(json.identifier);
    var username = String(json.accountName);
    var siteName = String(json.siteName);
    console.log(json);
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label for="Hierarchy">hierarchy</label>
<select name="hierarchy" id="hierarchy" value="">
  <option value=""></option>
  <option value="Staff">staff</option>
  <option value="Teacher"> teacher</option>
  <option value="Student">student</option>
</select>

uk.snstest.judgeservice.co.uk/api.php? usa.snstest.judgeservice.co.uk/api.php? france.snstest.judgeservice.co.uk/api.php? so depedning what country
student=uk staff=usa teacher=france
```

If you plan to add further options to your dropdown, I suggest you use an object with the `key` being the option value, and the value of the key is the function to trigger the API call.

Moreover, with the above code, you can use `api_login()` with the country passed through. You still need to add your other arguments but as you haven't provided what they are I haven't included them. Also, note that the URL API's which you linked currently don't work with the country appended to the front

Comment: Thanks very much, could you show me an example on how to add the corresponding api call?

Comment: @Falakii- I can't as I don't know what API your using

Comment: The URL doesn't link to anything... (site can't be reached)

Comment: Okay, do you know the parameters used to query the API (the query string to attach) ? Eg: I need to know what `snstest.judgeservice.co.uk/api.php?this=Student` <--- the `this` is

Comment: thats how i currently login but i want to add the drop down with a list of 3  different api calls

Comment: ok, how do you want the API calls to differ from each other? (eg: do you want the `dealer_code` to change, the `userid_code` to be different?

Comment: ok, so lets say I select "student" this will do an API call to the `uk` api, now if I choose "teacher" do you want this to do a call to a different country's API?

Comment: yh thats exactly what i want

Comment: Ok, so can you tell me what selection value corresponds with what country? Eg: "student" corresponds with `uk`, "teacher" corresponds with `us`, "staff" corresponds with ...?

Comment: Ok, I've edited my answer. Please note that when you call the `api_login()` function you still must pass through all your arguments. Also you can see the lines I've edited in your function by the commented lines. Lastly, uk.snstest.judgeservice.co.uk/api.php? usa.snstest.judgeservice.co.uk/api.php? france.snstest.judgeservice.co.uk/api.php?  aren't currently up and running so it won't currently work

Comment: thank you for your help, just a quick question where did you get the parameter country from

Comment: When I call the function `api_login` I pass through `country`. The country I pass through is based on the selection I make and is determines in the `change` event's function. So if the value is "Student" I pass through `"uk"` as the country (`api_login("uk")`) so that I can use `uk.snstest.judgeservice.co.uk/api.php?` as my API to query. So the `country` is added to the front of the URL.

Comment: hi is there any chance you can help me further, i can send you my email etc

Comment: @Falakii- hey, I might be able to - depending on how big the task is :P - Do you think you could open a new question with what you need help with?

Comment: its still same question its just that i couldn't get it to work when adding the code to my actual code base, wondering if i could send you the code and see if you can make it work?

Comment: @Falakii- ok, you just need to let me know what each parameter should be in the URL. If you upload your project to GitHub or Google docs I can download it and take a look