# jquery select change event happen and keyboard navigation

Tags: jquery, onchange

this issue was related to [jquery select option click handler 9 years old question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5749597/jquery-select-option-click-handler).

I have a dropdow, this dropdown can be really big.
I want to autosubmit the form when dropdown are updated.

- If i use on("click") event : it work good with Firefox, but didn't work with Chromium.
- If i use on("change") event : it work on both (and surely other) **but** : unable to go to the last element, the change event happen when option is selected by keyboard
- If i use on("blur") event : it work when change, but without select update too …

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
     $("#onchange").change(function(){
     /* this happen at bb, no way to set FF */
        $("#form").submit();
   });
     $("#onblur").blur(function(){
        /* happen without update */
        $("#form").submit();
   });
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="form">
<label for="onchange">onchange</label>
<select name="onchange" id="onchange">
<option value="aa" selected="selected">AA</option>
<option value="bb">BB</option>
<option value="cc">CC</option>
<option value="dd">DD</option>
<option value="ee">EE</option>
<option value="ff">FF</option>
</select>
<hr>
<label for="onblur">onblur</label>
<select name="onblur" id="onblur">
<option value="aa" selected="selected">AA</option>
<option value="bb">BB</option>
<option value="cc">CC</option>
<option value="dd">DD</option>
<option value="ee">EE</option>
<option value="ff">FF</option>
</select>
<hr>
<input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

Did someone have a good solution to disable select change event with keyboard navigation ?

Thank you

Screencast :

- Firefox 84.0.2 (64 bits) / Linux [image: Firefox 84.0.2 (64 bits)]
- Chromium Version 87.0.4280.88 / Linux (64 bits) [image: Chromium]

Comment: Looks like it works to me! I can move up and down with keyboard commands without it triggering the form submit.

Comment: Added 2 screencast for proof: Firefox 84 and Chromium 87

Comment: Strange, works fine on Chrome Version 71.0.3578.98 (Official Build) (64-bit) MacOSX because it opens up a dropdown rather than cycling through the values I guess. Not sure how to work around that without the issues you have with `blur`, hopefully someone can help

Answer (score 1):

Here is a suggestion for a "fix" for that uncool behavior...

On `Tab` key up, if the `select` is focussed, save the value. Submit the form only if the value has changed between the `focus` and the `blur` event.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  let selectVal
  
  $(document).on("keyup", function(e){
    if(e.key==="Tab" && $("#onblur").is(":focus")){
      selectVal = $("#onblur").val()
      console.log("val setted")
    }
  })

  $("#onblur").blur(function() {
    if (selectVal !== $(this).val()) {
      $("#form").submit();
    }else{
      console.log("Value was not changed")
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="form">

  <label for="onblur">onblur</label>
  <select name="onblur" id="onblur">
    <option value="aa" selected="selected">AA</option>
    <option value="bb">BB</option>
    <option value="cc">CC</option>
    <option value="dd">DD</option>
    <option value="ee">EE</option>
    <option value="ff">FF</option>
  </select>
  <hr>
  <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

For many selects... Here is the variant using the `.onblur` class.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  let selects = $(".onblur")
  let selectVal
  
  $(document).on("keyup", function(e){
    if(e.key==="Tab" && selects.is(":focus")){
      selectVal = $(".onblur:focus").val()
      console.log("val setted")
    }
  })

  selects.blur(function() {
    if (selectVal !== $(this).val()) {
      $("#form").submit();
    }else{
      console.log("Value was not changed")
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="form">
  
  <label for="onblur1">onblur1</label>
  <select name="onblur1" id="onblur1" class="onblur">
    <option value="aa" selected="selected">AA</option>
    <option value="bb">BB</option>
    <option value="cc">CC</option>
    <option value="dd">DD</option>
    <option value="ee">EE</option>
    <option value="ff">FF</option>
  </select>
  <hr>
  <label for="onblur2">onblur2</label>
  <select name="onblur2" id="onblur2" class="onblur">
    <option value="aa" selected="selected">EE</option>
    <option value="bb">FF</option>
    <option value="cc">GG</option>
    <option value="dd">HH</option>
    <option value="ee">II</option>
    <option value="ff">JJ</option>
  </select>
  <hr>
  <label for="onblur3">onblur3</label>
  <select name="onblur3" id="onblur3" class="onblur">
    <option value="aa" selected="selected">KK</option>
    <option value="bb">LL</option>
    <option value="cc">MM</option>
    <option value="dd">NN</option>
    <option value="ee">OO</option>
    <option value="ff">PP</option>
  </select>
  <hr>
  <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

Using a data atribute, as you suggested in comments, may be even better! ;)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  let selects = $(".onblur")
  
  // Set a data attribute for each select
  selects.each(function(){
    $(this).data("selected", $(this).val())
  })
  
  // On blur, compare the value with the data attribute
  selects.blur(function() {
    if ($(this).data("selected") !== $(this).val()) {
      $("#form").submit();
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="form">
  
  <label for="onblur1">onblur1</label>
  <select name="onblur1" id="onblur1" class="onblur">
    <option value="aa" selected="selected">AA</option>
    <option value="bb">BB</option>
    <option value="cc">CC</option>
    <option value="dd">DD</option>
    <option value="ee">EE</option>
    <option value="ff">FF</option>
  </select>
  <hr>
  <label for="onblur2">onblur2</label>
  <select name="onblur2" id="onblur2" class="onblur">
    <option value="aa" selected="selected">EE</option>
    <option value="bb">FF</option>
    <option value="cc">GG</option>
    <option value="dd">HH</option>
    <option value="ee">II</option>
    <option value="ff">JJ</option>
  </select>
  <hr>
  <label for="onblur3">onblur3</label>
  <select name="onblur3" id="onblur3" class="onblur">
    <option value="aa" selected="selected">KK</option>
    <option value="bb">LL</option>
    <option value="cc">MM</option>
    <option value="dd">NN</option>
    <option value="ee">OO</option>
    <option value="ff">PP</option>
  </select>
  <hr>
  <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: I think using some data-selected , and set it when loaded, check it when blur out …

Comment: Yep, but still the onblur is not perfect with mouse  … maybe i can try with `on("blur click")` …

Comment: Yes... Why not?