# onClick remote validation for dropdown field

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, validation, remote-validation

I am using JQuery remote validation on drop-down field to check whether the selected field  already exists or not. The overall code is working fine and validates properly. But the issue is remote validation sending an ajax call after onChange event, means it is showing unique key validation error after clicking anywhere on page.

I want to validate it once user clicks on dropdown option. I tried `onclick:true` but it's not working. Please check my code:

```
$("#myform").validate({
  //   onclick:true,
  //   onkeyup:true,
  rules: {
    "customer[customer_personal_details_id]": {
        required: true,
        remote: {
            url: "/validation/check",
            type: "post",
            data: {
                columnVal: function () {
                    return $("#customer_customer_personal_details_id").val();
                }
            }
        }
    }
  },
  messages: {
    "customer[customer_personal_details_id]": {
         required: "Please Select Account Holder", 
        remote: "One active account already exists. Duplicate accounts are not allowed."}
  }
});
```

Thanks. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Instead of using onClick inside, try validating inside an onClick function.

Comment: There's no standard for click event on options. See this [related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1402227/jquery-click-event-on-select-option-element-in-chrome) and [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10103116/2049063)

Comment: @koala_dev: So, is there any trick available to achieve this?

Comment: @Ultimate Can you provide a link to the plugin you are using?

Comment: Which validation library are you using?

Answer (score 2):

The `select`'s change event is a much better indicator of when to validate but there's no `onchange` option. The following should work:

```
$(function() {
    $('select').on('change', function() {
        $(this).trigger('focusout');
    })
    .on('focusout',function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

Triggering `focusout` should trigger a validate to be fired on the `select` element unless the `onfocusout` option is set to `false`. You may want to prevent the default behavior of `focusout` so that it does not trigger a `remote` validation twice.

In the demo below you'll see that as soon as you select a new value in `select` element, an attempt to make an ajax call is made -- see network tab of dev tools -- and on `focusout` no request attempt is made.

[**JSFIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/fiddleyetu/VR8cp/)

> **onfocusout** *Type*: Boolean or Function() Validate elements (except
>   checkboxes/radio buttons) on blur. If nothing is entered, all rules
>   are skipped, except when the field was already marked as invalid.

```
http://jqueryvalidation.org/category/plugin/
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this - assuming you have <SELECT ID="DROPDOWN_ID">

```
$('#DROPDOWN_ID').on('click', function() { 
    $("#myform").validate();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I do not use: "JQuery Remote Validation", but this code might help you:

JavaScript code:

```
window . onload = function ()
{
    "use strict";
    document . querySelector ( "form#myform > select" ) . selectedIndex = -1;
}

function test ()
{
    "use strict";
    if ( typeof customOption === "undefined" ) { alert ( "FATAL SYSTEM ERROR !" ); return; }
    alert ( "Valid option selected ! Congratulations !\nYour selected value is: \"" + customOption + "\"" );
}
```

and the HTML5 code:

```
<select onchange="customOption = this . options [ this . selectedIndex ] . value;">
<!-- ( ... ) -->
</select>
```

This is only demonstration. You can call your function, so you can: "validate it once user clicks on dropdown option" by change HTML5 code ( select element onchange attribute ).

Working fiddle: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aucyZ/)