# Get changed value from <select> using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I am trying to get the changed value of a `<select>` input using **jQuery**.

**Before change**

```
<select class="input" multiple="multiple" name="inputUserRoles[]">
  <option value="Administrator">Administrator</option>
  <option value="Faculty" selected="selected">Faculty</option>
  <option value="Head of Department">Head of Department</option>
  <option value="Faculty Coordinator" selected="selected">Faculty Coordinator</option>
</select>
```

**After change**

```
<select class="input" multiple="multiple" name="inputUserRoles[]">
  <option value="Administrator">Administrator</option>
  <option value="Faculty" selected="selected">Faculty</option>
  <option value="Head of Department">Head of Department</option>
  <option value="Faculty Coordinator">Faculty Coordinator</option>
</select>
```

If you notice, after the change event, the option 'Faculty Coordinator' is not `selected`.

I wish to get the value 'Faculty Coordinator'.

**My javascript code**

```
$('select[name="inputUserRoles[]"]').change(function(e) {
  // this line gives me the value after the change event.
  var inputUserRoles = $(this).val();
});
```

### Possible Solutions?

I was thinking that the event **(e)** should be containing the changed data but I have no idea how to get it. The project I am working on is in its final phase and I just need to figure out this part to complete the similar remaining modules.

The other way to get this done is by getting the old input and comparing.

Comment: But why are there two options selected?

Comment: @Aniket : Did you checked http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4076770/getting-value-of-select-dropdown-before-change

Comment: @Purmou It's a multi select box. That is why there are two selected options.

Comment: @Jithin I have looked at that question, but it's not what I am looking for.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Do that:

```
var valueBeforeChange = $('select[name="inputUserRoles[]"]').val();

$('select[name="inputUserRoles[]"]').change(function(e) {
  var inputUserRoles = $(this).val();

  //you can compare here with value before change
  ...

  valueBeforeChange = inputUserRoles;
});
```

Comment: Even I thought of comparing the old input and the new one but that it is a little troublesome. Is this is the only way possible?

Comment: I think so because I do not think the event object can store this information.

Comment: I am not very good as **js**, so is there a function with which I can compare two arrays and find out the difference directly? :P

Comment: there is no function for that, you must iterate through the first array and see if your value is present in the second.

Comment: I am now sending the complete array to my controller and using `array_diff` in PHP to get the job done. It is much more simple and suits my needs :) Thanks.