# Catch onchange event for a dynamically created Select using name

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have used [Event binding on dynamically created elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements) and [Get changed value from <select> using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11664399/get-changed-value-from-select-using-jquery) to get to where I am now.

I am creating a Select dropdown dynamically and would like to capture the selected item.

My code is:

```
$(document).on('click', '#programDetailTablebody button[name="addPDRow"]', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    
    var newRows = "";
                newRows += "<tr><td class='button'><button type='button' name='addPDRow' class = 'buttonFront'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-plus'></span></button></td>";
                newRows += "<td class='keyvalue'><input class='timeWidth timeClass pdValue' name='timeInput' value='07:00'></input></td>"; //Time
                newRows += "<td class='keyvalue'><select class='form-control activityTypeWidth activityTypeClass pdValue' name='activityTypeInput'>" //Activity Type
                newRows += "<option value='' disabled selected>Select Activity Type</option>" + activityTypeOptions + "</select>"
                newRows += "<td class='keyvalue'><select class='form-control activityWidth activityClass pdValue' name='activityInput'>" //Activity
                newRows += "<option value='' disabled selected>Select Activity</option>" + activityOptions + "</select>"
                newRows += "<td class='keyvalue'><input class='equipmentClass pdValue' name='equipmentInput'></input></td>";//Equip. Needed
                newRows += "<td class='keyvalue'><input class='awardClass pdValue' name='awardInput'></input></td>";//Award
                newRows += "<td class='keyvalue'><input class='leadersClass pdValue' name='leadersInput'></input></td>";//Leaders
                newRows += "<td class='button'><button type='button' name='removePDRow' class = 'buttonFront'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-minus'></span></button></td></tr>";
        
    $(newRows).insertAfter($(this).closest('tr'));
});

$("select[name='activityTypeInput']").on( 'change', 'option', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    alert("Changed");
    var activityType = $(this).val();
    alert(activityType);
});
```

This is the page:

[image]

The alerts are not triggered when I select an option and there are no errors in the console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As in the [accepted answer in the link you provided](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements#answer-1207393), you can use event binding on the existing parent element (in this case, for example, you can use #programDetailTablebody).

So instead of using

```
$("select[name='activityTypeInput']").on( 'change', 'option', function (e) { ... }
```

You an use

```
$('#programDetailTablebody').on( 'change', "select[name='activityTypeInput']", function (e) { ... }
```