# Storing Data In Jquery with onchange events

Tags: jquery, html

expanding on my last question  how can I store the last selected value from my dropdown but each time the user changes his pick I keep (*the previous selected value*) and (*the current selected value*). Do i need to use an array and use push/pop or is there another way to do this?

```
$(document).on('change', 'select[name=options]', function() {

var prev_selected =  $(this).val();
$(this).data('prev_selected',prev_selected);
alert(prev_selected );


//alert(current_selected );

});
```

**HTML**

```
<table id="Final">
<thead>
<th>Tie</th> <th>Pie</th><th>Lie</th>
</thead>

<tr>
<td><select class="Member" name="options">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">ball</option>
    <option value="4">4</option></td>
    <td>
    <select class="Member" name="options" price="200">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option></td>

    <td>
    <select class="Member" name="options" price="200">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">shoe</option>
    <option value="4">4</option></td>

    </tr>

    </table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You basically want to capture that previous value on focus, which occurs before the change.

Here's a similar post answering your question: [Getting value of select (dropdown) before change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4076770/getting-value-of-select-dropdown-before-change)

```
(function () {
    var previous;

    $("select").focus(function () {
        // Store the current value on focus, before it changes
        previous = this.value;
    }).change(function() {
        // Do something with the previous value after the change
        alert(previous);
    });
})();
```