# transfered data from a select to another and vice versa

Tags: php, jquery, select

I have 2 selects (a,b). Same data in both select.
I want that when I choose an option in one of them, the same option disapear in the second one. If a reselect an other option, the one tha disapeared should reappears

tx

Comment: Do you have any code that you could show us? What have you tried?

Comment: That is not a very clear question. Try to show us some code/progress, be more code-specific in general.

Comment: why you want to do that? choosing multiple item in select? if yes use `<select size="3" multiple="multiple">` and also check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2407284/how-to-get-multiple-selected-values-of-select-box-in-php

Comment: are the options in the same order?

Comment: i have seen this question so many times...

Comment: I've found an answere for my question [here][1]

Sorry!!
  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4076770/getting-value-of-select-dropdown-before-change

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check here http://jsfiddle.net/RTzwL/

html

```
<select id="first">
    <option value="india">India</option>
    <option value="usa">USA</option>
    <option value="japan">Japan</option>
    <option value="australia">Australia</option>
</select>

<select id="second">
    <option value="india">India</option>
    <option value="usa">USA</option>
    <option value="japan">Japan</option>
    <option value="australia">Australia</option>
</select>
```

Javascript

```
$('select').change(function() {
    $(this).siblings('select').find('option').attr({disabled:false});
   var thisIndex = parseInt($(this)[0].selectedIndex)+1;
    $(this).siblings('select').find('option:nth-child('+thisIndex+')').attr({disabled:true});
});
```