# jquery chosen before change event

Tags: jquery, jquery-chosen

I want to capture a before change event of jquery chosen, so if the value clicked in chosen is not the required one, it just do nothing and go back to previous selected option. Is it possible?

something like

```
$('.chzn-select').chosen({
    'beforeChange': function(){
        //if option clicked is Option-3
        //do nothing

    }
});
```

Answer (score 6):

With the help of [**data**](http://api.jquery.com/data/) jQuery function, `change` event and `params.selected` argument you can easily achieve that.

```
$(".chzn-select").chosen().on("change", function (evt, params) {
    if (params.selected === "Portugal") {
        var previous = $(this).data("previous") || "";
        $(this).val(previous).trigger("chosen:updated");
    } else {
        $(this).data("previous", params.selected);
    }
});
```

**[See this working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ejQ5K/)**

Comment: But this will work incorrectly if you have something selected by default.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this

```
(function () {
    var previous;    
    $(".chzn-select").focus(
        function () {
    // Store the current value on focus and on change
        previous = $(this).val();
    }).change(function() {
        if($(this).val()=="Option-3"){// //if option clicked is Option-3
            $(this).val(previous); // select the value prior to the change
            $(this).trigger("chosen:updated"); // tell chosen to pick up the updated value      
        }
    });
})();
```

I have taken the idea from : [Getting value of select (dropdown) before change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4076770/getting-value-of-select-dropdown-before-change)