# OnChange - get previous value?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is it possible to get the previous value from the OnChange event from a drop down? I need to see the previous selected value, so that I can make a decision on what I should display.

At the moment, I get the new value:

```
var id = $('.cmbType').val();
```

But would like to know what it was before the user selected this value.

Comment: I think this has already been answered here [Getting value of select (dropdown) before change][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4076770/getting-value-of-select-dropdown-before-change

Answer (score 3):

You have to store the previous value yourself:

```
// store initial value
var initialValue = $('.cmbType').val();
$('.cmbType').data('previousValue', initialValue);

// change handler
$('.cmbType').change(function(e) {

    var previousValue = $(this).data('previousValue');

    // make decision
    alert(previousValue);

    // store previousValue
    $(this).data('previousValue', $(this).val());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try some thing like this:

```
<select id='cmbType'>
    <option value='1' >1</option>
    <option value='2' >2</option>
    <option value='3' >3</option>
</select>
```

javascript:

```
var preSelected = -1;
$(function(){
    $('#cmbType').bind('click change', function(e){
        if(e.type == 'change'){
            // change value detect
            alert(preSelected);
        }
        else{
            // click
            preSelected = $(this).val();
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: What if user, focused to that input by pressing `tab` button ? then click event won't be triggered.

Answer (score -2):

You can use: **.defaultValue**
Will give you the value.

Comment: This is wrong, the object . **defaultValue** property gives you the value set in the HTML code. See [link](http://help.dottoro.com/ljnqsrfe.php)