# How to get the value of a select tag which doesn't change on hover?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-select

I'm using jQuery's `.val()` function to read the value of a `<select>` tag. 
It seems that, at least in Firefox, `.val()` returns the value of the option the user is currently hovering over. You can see this behaviour at [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ubqs83at/).

Is there any way using jQuery or pure javascript to get the value that is shown in the select box, i.e. the last value that actually fired a change event?

### Original Idea

```
function foo() {
    var value = $('#select').val();
    // do something that depends on value
}
```

The problem with this is that I only want `foo()` to use the value that is currently **selected**. By **selected** I mean the option that was **clicked**. In the fiddle, you can see that this value changes as you hover over options.

### Alternative

```
var value;

$('#select').change(function() {
    value = $('#select').val();
}

function foo() {
    // do something with value
}
```

This is OK, but the information appears to exist in the DOM, since the last clicked value is displayed in the select box.

So, my question is, is it possible to get the last clicked option from the DOM?

Comment: Is this what you are talking about?
$('#bar').change(function (){
    $('#foo').text($('#bar').val());
}).trigger("change");

Comment: Your question is not clear.

Comment: What is not clear about it?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4076770/getting-value-of-select-dropdown-before-change

Comment: In your Fiddle, the value doesn't change when you hover over an option, it changes once you select one. You are already capturing the last value that fired a change event (after 100ms of that event firing anyway). Like in Sunand's suggestion, though, it would be more efficient to add a handler for the change event, instead of firing your own event 10 times a second.

Comment: @mark.hch. In my browser it does change when you hover over an option. Maybe it is browser dependent? I am using Firefox 24.7.0.

Comment: does this alert for you when you hover? `$('select').change(function() {alert();});` are you sure you're not confusing highlight with a selection being made?

Comment: @Brian, no that does not alert. I understand that the change event is only fired after a selection is made, but the **value** returned by `val()` **does** change when highlighting an option.

Comment: How do you know that if the change event isn't firing?

Comment: Check out the fiddle. In my real code, the function `foo` is being run periodically and depends on the value of the select tag.

Comment: Ah I see it now, my apologies. You won't have to worry about that if you retrieve the value after the change event has taken place and not at an interval.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60579/discussion-between-user545424-and-brian).

Comment: I added an answer of using focus below, helpful?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this on the `change` event instead of by interval

**UPDATED CODE** based on comments below

```
$('#bar').on('change', function(){
  var $t =$(this) , value=$t.val();
  $t.attr('data-answer', value);
});

setInterval(function(){
 $('#foo').text($('#bar').attr('data-answer'));
},1000);
```

your select would have this attribute on it

```
<select id="bar" data-answer="" >
 //options here
</select>
```

Or using `.data` method:

```
$('#bar').on('change', function(){
  var $t =$(this) , value=$t.val();
  $t.data('answer', value);
});

setInterval(function(){
 $('#foo').text($('#bar').data('answer'));
},1000);
```

Comment: You can not get the value that is hovered over by the mouse as no event has occurred at that point.

Comment: This works, but since other functions depend on the value, I'd prefer not to store the state in two places. See my updated question. I'm interested in whether it is possible to get this value directly from the DOM, or whether I need to store the state myself.

Comment: Add a `data` attribute onto your select to hold the previously selected item. i will update answer.

Comment: That would be helpful, but I'm more interested in whether it is possible to get this information from the DOM without adding anything. It seems to know what the last clicked value was, because it appears in the select box. Is that data accessible? I would be happy with knowing that it's not possible, and then I have to store it myself.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand `$('#bar').val();` is getting the value from the DOM. You can use the `data` method from jQuery instead of the `.attr` method.  jQuery stores its own copy of the data elements there and they can be read back at any time whether they exist in the markup or not. You would use it like `.data('answer')` instead of `.attr('data-answer');`

Comment: I just mean that when you click the select box, the last clicked option still appears in the box. So that information is stored **somewhere**. Is it available in the DOM? Is there any way to access that? Or once you hover over an option that becomes the currently selected option and there is no way to get the last value that was clicked absent you storing it in a variable yourself?

Comment: FYI: you can not get the previous value from the change event because the value has changed when the event fires. That's why you store the previous value in a data attribute so that you can get it even after the event has fired.

Comment: @Brian, that's not true in my browser. Maybe it is an issue with Firefox, but in the fiddle I posted, the `.val()` returns different values when you hover over the options.

Comment: Here is a fiddle that displays the previous value as well as the current value.  http://jsfiddle.net/x4arsg92/4/

Comment: And here is it update to use `data` instead of `attr`.  http://jsfiddle.net/x4arsg92/5/

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you're looking for [focus()](http://api.jquery.com/focus/)

```
$("select").focus(function () {

    var focusValue = this.value;

    $('#foo').text(focusValue);

})
```

You can chain the event listener `focus` with `change` to find the current value and then the selected.

```
$("select").focus(function () {

    var focusValue = this.value;

    $('#foo').text(focusValue);

}).change(function() {

    var changeValue = this.value  

    $('#foo').text(changeValue);

});
```

Here is a [jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ubqs83at/3/)