# Javascript/Jquery method to get previous selected value of a dropdown on change event

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have following php with javascript code snippet.

```
 <td align="center">
    <select id = "selectedUnit" class="form-control" onchange="saveToDatabase(this.value,'Unit','<?php echo $ingredientArray[$i][0]; ?>')"><?php 
                                                $j=0;
                                                for($j=0;$j<count($unitTypeArray);$j++) { ?>
                                                    <option value="<?php echo $unitTypeArray[$j][0]; ?>" <?php if($ingredientArray[$i][4] == $unitTypeArray[$j][0]){ echo 'selected';} ?>><?php echo $unitTypeArray[$j][1]; ?></option><?php 
                                                } ?>
                                            </select>
    </td>
```

Above is my dropdown , what I want is to get the previous selected value on dropdown change event , like below.

```
function saveToDatabase(editableObj,column,id) {
    //editableObj gives me the currently changing value .
    // How I will get the previous selected value ?I am doing it as follows.
    var $selected = $(this).find(':selected');   
       var text = $selected.prev().text(); //previous value
}
```

Please help me on this .Thanks.

Comment: Use variable which will maintain previous value whenever there is change..

Comment: @ImranQamer How onchange will solve this , can you please give me a hind writing code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first option try this js code, but when u will change first time then there will be no previous selected value.

```
 var previous;

    function saveToDatabase(editableObj,column,id) {
       alert(previous); //print previous value
       var $selected = $(this).find(':selected');   
       previous= $selected.text();
    }
```

second option change this line

```
<select id = "selectedUnit" class="form-control" onchange="saveToDatabase(this.value,'Unit','<?php echo $ingredientArray[$i][0]; ?>')">
```

to this

```
<select id = "selectedUnit" class="form-control" onclick="saveToDatabase(this.value,'Unit','<?php echo $ingredientArray[$i][0]; ?>')">
```

and js for this will be

```
function saveToDatabase(editableObj,column,id) {
       var $selected = $(this).find(':selected');   
       previous= $selected.text();
       alert(previous);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks! ,  you really saved my time on what I got stuck for an hour .

Comment: you welcome, always accept the correct answer by clicking on tick symbol for users who will visit in future

Answer (score 1):

What you were doing is firing a function on `onchange` or `focus` event. It fires when the value is changed. So you can't get previous value.

The event you should work is `onclick` that will give you the previous value and then `onchange` can be fired to get changed value. I suggest below strategy if you are using `jQuery`:

```
var previous;

    $("select").on('focus', function () {
        // Store the current value on focus and on change
        previous = this.value;
    }).change(function() {
        // Do something with the previous value after the change
        alert(previous);

        // Make sure the previous value is updated
        previous = this.value;
    });
```

You can find it here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/4076949/1957479