# How to use jQuery onChange with if / else statement's?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a problem with javascript running because it is cashed.

**Example**

```
//Init onClick event
$(document).on('click', '.select', function(){
    //Check if select has value
    if( $(this).val() ){
        console.log( $(this).val() )
    } else {
        console.log('no value')

        $(this).on('change', function(){
            console.log('Changed!')
        }
    }
}
```

**PROBLEM**
Now consider i have a select. From start the value is empty and the option is disabled. First time i click the select, console will log "no value". 
You click and you change option/value to something in the list.

Second time i click the select, an option is selected and it has a value. Console will now log "the value", but it will also log "changed".

I guess it's because i have run the else statement before and the onChange function is cashed in my browser or something like it...

How can i prevent this from happen.. or how should i write my code instead?
 I need to check if a value is selected from start.. and i need to use the onChange function...

**UPDATE**
When you click the select, i'd like to know if the select has a selected value. (To know if you change/edit a value OR if you choose value for first time) This is why i have a onClick function. Here i check the value.

After you clicked and i have checked the value, i like to trigger a onChange function.. that will do this for the edit route.. or that for the new route..

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? I can't figure it out.

Comment: `change` listener will not invoke its handler if it is disabled.. Use `$('.select').on('change', function(){
      console.log('Changed!')
      }` as you have `click` listener..

Comment: I have now tried to explain more...

Comment: @Rayon my select's are dynamic added. I cannot use a selector like ".select" i need to use document to find it.. and this to specify it..

Comment: @Mjukis — Well in that case, Read about [__`Event delegation`__](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should only add "*change*" event on the select.
Operations on a select element must be done in terms of it's *state changed* w.r.t it's options

```
 var pervious;
 //Init onClick event
$(document).on('focus','.select', function () {
    // Store the current value on focus and on change
    previous = this.value;
}).
on('change', '.select', function(){
    //Check if select has value
    if( $(this).val() ){
      console.log( $(this).val() );
      previous = this.value;
    }
    else{
      console.log('no value')
      // YOUR choice, reset it i.e. previous = null;
    }
});
```

Comment: I need the click.. to do my first check.. if the change is an edit..or first choice..

Comment: @Mjukis - no, you probably don't need a `click`, you simply need to trigger the `change` event to fire the function when you start your app. `$('.select').trigger('change')`

Comment: @Mjukis click on select always end's up on 'change' event as you are going to select some option. I dont understand your logic here. Also you can as suggested trigger an change event for your app initialization if really requires to do so

Comment: I use the onClick to get the value that is chosen before i change.. maby i can get that in the change to?

Comment: @Mjukis yes that is correct. So register only change event as i suggested. If that helped please accept answer :)

Comment: Like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4076770/getting-value-of-select-dropdown-before-change

Comment: But your answer will give me the newly SELECTED value... not the value that is selected BEFORE i change it to a new?!

Comment: @Mjukis your question no where expects this :) but if link suggested what you want then you should try that.

Comment: @Mjukis I have updated my answer from your current clear requirement. check if that helps now.

Answer (score 0):

The main problem I see on your code is that you are binding the `change` listener inside the `click` listener, so every time you `click` you bind another `change` event, giving you the idea of cashed `onchange` function. Take your change function outside the click delegating it properly. Something like:

```
$(document).on('click', '.select', function(){
    //Check if select has value
    if( $(this).val() ){
        console.log( $(this).val() )
    } else {
        console.log('no value')
    }
})
$(document).on('change', '.select', function(){
    console.log('Changed!')
})
```