# Is it possible to find from what value a .change() was triggered?

Tags: jquery

From a `<select>` tag, is it possible to find **from** what value the `.change()` was triggered?

Comment: cache value in a variable

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting value of select (dropdown) before change](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4076770/getting-value-of-select-dropdown-before-change)

Comment: @Ryad.iv: To be pedantic, I don't need it before change, but after it has been changed. For this to be a duplicate the earlier post need a title edit.

Comment: Just to be clear in the example provided by @PranavCBalan what value do you need the prev or the current.

Comment: I need the previous value. But the title of the earlier post is ambiguous because you could read it as needing the value of the select before the .change() is fired.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a variable for cache the previous value.

```js
// bind change event handler to the eleemnt 
// and cache the current value in `prev`
var prev = $('#test').change(function() {
  // get previous value from `prev`
  console.log('prev : ' + prev + ' , current : ' + this.value);

  //... do the rest here

  // update the `prev` variable with current value
  prev = this.value;
}).val(); // get the default value
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="test">
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="11">11</option>
  <option value="111">111</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a sample, You just have to get the `value` of the `select` initially on page load, Then every time there is a change just update this variable with new value.

At any change event the variable `currValue` holds the previous value before change.

```js
var currValue = $('select').val();

$('select').on('change',function(){
  var newValue = $(this).val();
  alert('value Before change : '+ currValue);
  alert('value After change : '+ newValue);
  
  currValue = newValue;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select>
  <option>1</option>
  <option>2</option>
  <option>3</option>
  <option>4</option>
<select>
```

Answer (score 1):

If I'm not wrong this is what you are asking for:

```js
(function () {
    var previous;

    $("select[name=test]").focus(function () {
        // Store the current value on focus, before it changes
        previous = this.value;
    }).change(function() {
        // Do soomething with the previous value after the change
        document.getElementById("log").innerHTML = "<b>Previous: </b>"+previous;
        
        previous = this.value;
    });
})();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="test">
    <option value="stack">Stack</option>
    <option value="overflow">Overflow</option>
    <option value="my">My</option>
    <option value="question">Question</option>
</select>
<div id="log"></div>
```