# I am trying to determine whether a variable matches the option selected in the drop down box. How can I do this?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I have created a basic drop down list. I am simply trying to select the value currently showing in the drop down list, save it in a variable, and print it in the console. The end goal is to compare that variable to another variable to determine if the selection was correct.

I am a novice , so I assuming no one needs to know my poor attempts here...

```
<div id="Selections">
    <div id="game1">
        <p> Saturday 1:00PM EST   Team 1 vs Team 2 </p>
        <select id="game1Pick">
            <option>Team 1</option>
            <option>Team 2</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

I expect the console to print whatever I have selected, but I keep getting errors.

Comment: This is a JavaScript or a JQuery question -- it should not be tagged with "Java", as the Java language is not involved at all.

Comment: *"I am a novice , so I assuming no one needs to know my poor attempts here..."*  Yes, we do.  You showing your attempt changes this question from a coding request to an "I have an issue with logic, help me" valid question.

Answer (score 0):

You need an onchange function to detect what value you have selected. Example:

```
<div id="Selections">
    <div id="game1">
        <p> Saturday 1:00PM EST   Team 1 vs Team 2 </p>
        <select id="game1Pick" onchange="myFunction()">
            <option>Team 1</option>
            <option>Team 2</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("game1Pick").value;
  console.log('Selected Value is -> ', x);
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var teamVal = "team-1";
$('#game1Pick').on('change', function(){
  if($(this).val() == teamVal){
    alert('variable matches the option');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="Selections">
    <div id="game1">
        <p> Saturday 1:00PM EST   Team 1 vs Team 2 </p>
        <select id="game1Pick">
            <!--use value 1st for options -->
            <option value="">--select--</option>
            <option value="team-1">Team 1</option>
            <option value="team-2">Team 2</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

Please check this I did some changes in HTML and I use some jQuery for it.

Answer (score 0):

Below i have directly passed the selected object in onChange.
And If you also want the value before onchange also you can refer this link.
[Getting value of select (dropdown) before change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4076770/getting-value-of-select-dropdown-before-change/21165613)

```js
function printValue(obj) {
    console.log('Selected Value is --> ', obj.value);
    //put the condition 
}
```

```html
 <div id="Selections">
    <div id="game1">
        <p> Saturday 1:00PM EST   Team 1 vs Team 2 </p>
        <select id="game1Pick" onchange="printValue(this);">
            <option>Team 1</option>
            <option>Team 2</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```